# Sparse autoencoder for Weka

Tags: machine-learning, weka, deep-learning, autoencoder

I don't have much knowledge about it but there is a way to use a sparse autoencoder in Weka? At this time, I've just used MPLAutoencoder and don't have certain if I can configure it for sparsing too. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I've asked the author of MPLAutoencoder and there isn't an implementation of a sparse autoencoder in Weka yet.